# Package hyperref conflicts with counter inside section title

Tags: hyperref

The following minimal document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{projno}
\newcommand{\proj}{%
\stepcounter{projno}%
\theprojno}


\begin{document}

\section{Project \protect\proj }

\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname
l.14 \section{Project \protect\proj }
```

The error disappears when I comment out `\usepackage{hyper ref}`. Does anyone see a way out of this dilemma ?

Comment: You should step `projno` before `\section` and use `\theprojno` in the title. There's a recent question very similar to yours.

Comment: @egreg : I know, but this is not very convenient to increment manually. But if there is no other way, I will follow your kind advice.

Comment: My recommendation is to define `\newcommand{\project}{\stepcounter{projno}\section{Project \theprojno}`. You get a good markup anyway, by just starting the section with `\project`.

Answer (score 4):

The macro `\proj` causes trouble in the bookmarks. Most of TeX's stomach machinery does not work here. Expandable commands work fine in bookmarks, but assignments (counter increments, ...) do not. Package `hyperref` provides `\texorpdfstring` or `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` to deal with commands that should be redefined or filtered out inside bookmarks:

```
\section{Project\texorpdfstring{\protect\proj}{\theprojno}}
```

Or `\proj` can be made known to `hyperref`'s bookmark code:

```
...
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\proj\theprojno}
...
\begin{document}
...
\section{Project\protect\proj}
```

Hints:

- If you defined `\proj` with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, then an explicit `\protect` is not needed, when using `proj`:

  ```
  \newcommand*{\proj}{}% check, whether \proj is undefined
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\proj}{\stepcounter{projno}}
  ```
- Important hint from egreg in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151848/package-hyperref-conflicts-with-counter-inside-section-title/151849#comment346377_151848): `\stepcounter` should be better used *before* `\section`. Otherwise the counter is also incremented by the entry in the table of contents and head lines (depending on the page style).